# When I run my app via npx react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPhone 14 Pro Max' I get the error Firebase is not configured

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, plist, firebase-analytics

I use the expo-firebase-analytics library. On Expo it works fine because it's via web. But when I run it via npx react-native run-ios it builds the app and I can use everything except Analytics even though I configured the plist file like below. I tried everything I could I really need the help.

PLIST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>xxxxx</string>
    <key>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>xxxx</string>
    <key>API_KEY</key>
    <string>xxxx</string>
    <key>GCM_SENDER_ID</key>
    <string>xxxxx</string>
    <key>PLIST_VERSION</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
    <string>xxxx</string>
    <key>PROJECT_ID</key>
    <string>xxxx</string>
    <key>STORAGE_BUCKET</key>
    <string>xxxx</string>
    <key>IS_ADS_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>
    <string>xxxx</string>
    <key>DATABASE_URL</key>
    <string>xxxx</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

```
app.json:

{
  "expo": {
    "name": "LUX",
    "slug": "lux",
    "owner": "lux_kaso",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./Pics/logo.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "bundleIdentifier": "lux.ios"
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "lux.android"
    },
    "web": {
      "config": {
        "firebase": {
          "apiKey": "xxxx",
          "authDomain": "xxxx",
          "projectId": "xxxx",
          "storageBucket": "xxxx",
          "messagingSenderId": "xxxx",
          "appId": "xxxx",
          "measurementId": "xxxx"
        }
      },
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxxx"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static",
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried:

- setting analytics in the Plist file true
- downloaded a fresh Plist file from Google
- moved the Plist file in the iOS directory
- asked ChatGPT